# .NET 4.0 MVC load error, what is this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, compression, iis-8, combres

I've been trying to launch my current project, but have started getting very strange 'errors' when the page won't load. I've recently tried to add Combres to my project, but it was happening on other errors (standard exceptions, SQL exceptions, whatever...) and I've no idea what it is. If anyone has seen this before, it would be great to get some clarity.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with IIS Express running the project in Google Chrome (though it happens in Firefox too).

I've included the internal server error that's reported. Could it have something to do with the compression?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Yes. Before you mentioned compression, it was the first thing I thought about. I used a custom compression module in a MVC project a while back and I got these kind of pages intermittently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was also using a custom compression attribute I had forgotten about (thanks, @Steve) which I presume was clashing with the Ombres settings, or at the very least, not decompressing properly. I removed those attributes anyway and the normal error pages turned up, which coincidentally related to Combres.